# AppendText doesn't happen in sequential order of my C# code?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am running a powershell script from my C# code..

```
        txtLogs.AppendText($"Initializing bootstrapping process for {padName}");

        /*
         * -x           : administrator username
         * -P           : administrator password
         * --msi-url    : URL location of the MSI file for the chef-client within L3
         * -r           : Role that the user run-list should execute on bootstrap execution
         * -N           : Node name that should dynamically be assigned to each server within the L3 network
        */
        string script = @"knife bootstrap windows winrm xx.xx.xx"
                            + " -x " + userName
                            + " -P " + passWord
                            + " --msi-url " + msiLocation
                            + " -r 'role[deploy]'"
                            + " -N " + padName;

        ps.AddScript(script);

        try
        {
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                if (outputItem != null)
                { .......
```

For some reason, it seems like the script runs before the text can actually get appended to the textbox. Why would this happen? It's all running in the same thread.

Edit: I found a workaround, not sure if it's the best way:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread, the textbox isn't updated until this code finishes.

Comment: The text is appended before but you see the result later because the main thread is busy.

Comment: You're most likely blocking the UI, which means your code runs to completion before the message loop processes the message to repaint your textbox.

Comment: New to windows dev stuff. How can I get around this? Edit: Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.Background);